# How to give write permission in c# console project

Tags: c#

I am a very new beginner in `c#` and I am following the Microsoft official of Bob Tabor. The course is great and keep me interested thoroughly.

Coming to problem, I am trying to write a file using `c#` console project on my Mac machine but I got permission denied error which is well explanatory though. I was not able to came across the solution as available solution shown by other post has lot of thing which I don't understand and I don't loose my interest by doing something which I don't understand. So I am looking simple and nice solution which make sense to me as of now being a absolute beginner.

Here is code my Mac machine

```
class Programme
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myName = "My name is Carlos";
        File.WriteAllText(@"/Users/username/Desktop", myName);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: is the `username` points to your username in os x?

Comment: Run IDE or your exe as administrator

Comment: I'm not sure about Mac, but before we can help you we need to know: 1st exist the directory `/Users/username/`, 2nd the `Desktop` is a file, or a directory? On Windows it would be a directory. Therefore you are missing a file name to save. 3rd when the file `Desktop` exist, what are its attributes? Have you write permission *(as running user of the application)*?

Comment: @Ramesh yes, username is pointing to my os x user

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than hard-coding the desktop's path, you should use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop)` which returns the path to the desktop.  You'll still need to append a filename to that before you use it, though.

```
string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "temp.txt");
File.WriteAllText(path, myName);
```

should work

Comment: I want to write output inside test folder which is available on desktop. How can I do that?

Comment: `Path.Combine` has overloads for additional arguments. So just something like `string path = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Desktop), "test", "temp.txt");`

Answer (score 6):

`File.WriteAllText` can not create folders `/Users/username` if they do not exist. Try:

```
File.WriteAllText(@"temp.txt", myName);
```

This will write to file `temp.txt` in folder with your program.

Comment: As a note if you don't know where your current executable directory is, you can use `Console.WriteLine(System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());`

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using mac, the program might not have write access. Use the terminal to navigate the parent folder and then give permissions to all users using CHMOD 777 foldername